# Limpar Form após submit e continuar na mesma pagina, apenas com PHP e Html

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

Criei um fomulário para cadastrar "Categorias" e "Produtos" no banco de dados, tudo está funcionando corretamente, porém gostaria de que quando eu clicasse no botão Salvar "Submit" ele limpasse os campus inputs depois de salvar no banco.

Ja tentei varias maneiras encontradas tanto neste como em outros fórum, porém  a maioria das soluções são via ajax que eu não tenho nenhum conhecimento ainda, se alguém puder me ajudar via PHP + Html desde já agradeço.

Gravacategoria.php:

```html
<?php
$nomecat=$_POST["txtcategoria"];

if(!empty($nomecat)){
    $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=loja","root","aula");

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('Insert into loja.categoria(nome)Values(:par_categoria)');
    $dados=array(":par_categoria"=>$nomecat);

    $result = $stmt->execute($dados);

    if($result){
        $mensagem = "Produto inserido com sucesso";
    }
    else{
        $mensagem = "Erro";
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        parent.document.getElementById("msgaqui").innerHTML = "<?php echo $mensagem ?>";
        
        // MINHA ULTIMA TENTATIVA, CHAMANDO A PAGINA DE CADASTRO DE NOVO, POREM TAMB EM NAO FUNCIONOU, OS CAMPOS CONTINUAM PREENCHIDO
        header("Location: pgcadpro.php");
    </script>
    <?php    
    }
    ?>
```

Cadastro.php:

```html
<form id="form-cat" target="gravar" method="post" action="gravacategoria.php">
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtproduto">Nova Categoria: </label>  
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="txtcategoria" name="txtcategoria" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btnsalvar"></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button id="btnsalvarcat" name="btnsalvar" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    <button type="reset" id="btncancelar" name="btncancelar" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div  class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="msgaqui"> </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Infelizmente você vai precisar do Javascript para isso, seja com AJAX ou jQuery, apenas com PHP e HTML você não conseguirá fazer, sendo porque o HTML é apenas sua estrutura e não consegue executar " ações " após algum evento e o PHP só interfere no lado do servidor. O Javascript que irá fazer essa funcionalidade do lado do cliente.

Comment: Acho que a solução do Leo é a mais indicada, contudo você pode tentar "enganar" o navegador, chamando a pagina de cadastro novamente, mas adicionando algum parâmetro na url, atribuindo um valor dinâmico, por exemplo:

header('Location: pgcadpro,php?clean=' . time());

Comment: Obrigado amigo, porem preciso entregar hoje e até agora sempre que precisei de uma soluçao para contornar meu problema sem ajax foi aqui que consegui, eu sei que o correto é estudar JavaScript porem como não sei como funciona e nao tenho tempo hoje de aprender, vou torcer para alguem aparecer com uma gambiarra. Obrigado

Comment: Não entendi o problema de não poder utilizar o header('Location') ... Quando eu utilizo o header voltando para a página de cadastro, os campos sempre limpam.

Comment: Já que sua página de cadastro é o cadastro.php, vc não deveria utilizar o header("Location: cadastro.php") ?

Comment: Thiaguinho então alguma ideia do pq o meu nao funciona?

Comment: Puis aqui cadastro.php para melhor entendimento o nome do arquivo esta correto, pgcadpro.php

Comment: Eu posso te sugerir uma gambiarra pesada que eu fiz uma fez. Você pode utilizar o header("Location") direcionando para uma página de confirmação de envio com e lá constar uma mensagem do tipo "Seu Cadastro foi Realizado com Sucesso" e nessa página você criar um botão direcionando novamente para a página de cadastro. Então, quando o usuário clicar nesse botão, ele volta para a página de cadastro.

Comment: Creio eu que seu ```header``` não esteja funcionando porque colocou ele dentro da TAG ```script```, é recomendado sempre deixar ele no final do seu script PHP, pois assim que todo o código for concluido, ele irá redirecionar o usuário para o ```Location``` definido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa fazer redirecionamento, até porque, você está se referindo à sua [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422657/8063) onde sugeri usar um iframe para gravar os dados, e a página será redirecionada dentro do iframe oculto, que não irá alterar a página principal.

Neste caso você pode fazer de de duas formas:

Esvaziando o campo:

```
parent.document.getElementById("txtcategoria").value = '';
```

Ou resetando o formulário:

```
parent.document.getElementById("form-cat").reset();
```

Pode ainda colocar o foco no campo após resetar o form:

```
parent.document.getElementById("txtcategoria").focus();
```

Comment: O tenso é que ele falou que não gostaria de utilizar JavaScript.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento mas ele já está usando. Dá uma olhada no `<script>`. Acho que ele se expressou errado quando diz com "apenas com PHP + HTML", e o JavaScript é nativo no navegador.

Comment: Está certo, Sam.

Comment: @Sam Muito obrigado, era isso que eu precisava. Só para eu entender parent.document.getElementById("form-cat").reset(); isso aqui é JavaScript??

Comment: É JavaScript sim.

Comment: Sam, eu estou bloqueado de fazer perguntas porem só tenho uma percuntar com -2 pois esta como duplicada, não consigo excluir pois diz que pessoas ja investiram tempo com ela e ajudou algumas... o que fazer?